# design template for different dataset per user in EF framework

Tags: c#, database-design

My question is on best practice. I am working on a webservice, that will host about 500 users.
Each user will only need their own data, but all data is of the same structure. Using EFM (model first, but can change to code-first), c#, visual studio, Web service, IIS for hosting)

How can I set this up? I can imagine:

1. a database per user - seems excessive, and need to find a host that will support his
2. login to the database with different users... but that doesn't shield the data by itself.
3. Model the user inside the database (link all items to user), and filter every request by user

3 seems the most feasible. This will require me to change a lot of my methods

- Are there other better solutions?
- is there an easy way to apply this user-filter on all cross-sections of the table? (I mean that every request will be "automatically" filtered to return only items that are owned by the user that is making the request).